# Returning the first IP from an IP array that can connect to a server

Tags: c#

There is an `IParray ips[]`, how can I return the first IP from an IP array that can connect to a server?

I've tried to use exception to check if an IP can connect, not by return value, so I don't how to return.

```
foreach (IPAddress x in ips) {
    try {
        var client = new TcpClient(x.ToString(), 2000);
        return x.ToString();
    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your idea is not wrong. To make all pretier and simple you could do something like this:

```
public void YourMethod
{
  foreach (IPAddress x in ips)
  {
    if(IsServerListening(x.ToString(), 2000))
    {
      //If you can connect, then exit the foreach loop (I assume you´ll do something else)
      break;
    }
  }
}

private bool IsServerListening(string server, int port)
{
    using(TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            client.Connect(server, port);
        }
        catch(SocketException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        client.Close();
        return true;
    }
}
```